# firefox not picking latest css in application using frames

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, caching

I am working on an enterprise application that uses frames. We have performed several changes to the javascript and css files in order to enhance the existing functionality.

I know browsers cache both the things so in order to overcome we are including the css and javscript files to inclue the version information for example

```
<script language="javascript" src="21225/scripts/common_ui_enu.js?v=1"></script>
<link href="files/bootstrap.css?v=2" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

This technique seems to be working in all other browsers except Firefox. 
The latest CSS is not picked up even after clearing the cache (even with ctrl + F5).
I am using firefox version 16.0.2 for my testing.

What is best way to ensure that latest css files are picked up by firefox for a framed application?

**EDIT**

The versioning technique might be old but it works. The problem that I found out was that there was syntax error in the CSS where one rule background URL was missing round bracket.

Firefox for some reason was ignoring all other css rules after that. Once the CSS was fixed Firefox also started to pick up the changes based on version provided in the include URL.

Comment: Do you change the `v` parameter every time you change the JS, or do you randomly generate it when printing the HTML?

Comment: I change it manually everytime js or css is changed (which is not very often)

Answer (score 0):

Using a query parameter is a very old-fashioned way to prevent caching, and not reliable on HTTP 1.1. Look at using proper caching headers: [`expires`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.21) and such.

Comment: It is an enterprise application so I don't have complete control over the HTTP headers that are generated. Can this be done by meta tags in page ? If possible can please provide an example of the same?

Comment: @user1017268: *"It is an enterprise application so I don't have complete control over the HTTP headers that are generated"* Why not? This should be something any decent enterprise application gives you control over. *"Can this be done by meta tags in page ?"* Yes: `<meta http-equiv="expires" content="....">`. More: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-meta-element.html#the-meta-element

Comment: if I provide a static expiration date (example: october 20 2012) in http-equiv tag then wouldn't it be that all the css, javascript files would be requested every time the page is visited after the provided date (after 20th)?

Comment: @user1017268: The expiration date you give for a CSS file has exactly ***zero*** effect on the caching of JS files. In terms of supplying a static date: That's why you use a proper server, because any half-decent server can be configured to send an `expires` header based on the time the resource is requested (e.g., "this resource is valid for a day / week / month / year / decade / epoch").

Comment: I guess in that case I am out of luck as this app doesn't provide me this ability. Is there any other way to do it?